# Should we have [birthday-paradox] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-proposal

Currently there are approximately 13 mentioning [birthday paradox](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=birthday+paradox+is%3Aquestion) and another 22 mentioning [birthday problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=birthday%20problem%20is%3Aquestion) (I guess there could be more). In most cases it is the main topic of the questions. Should we have separate tag for it? It is pretty important topic in probability so it may be worth having a tag.

Comment: speaking personally (i.e. as a user) I'd lean toward having it

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since there is no answers and not much comments, while the question and pro-tag comments received several up-votes I would consider creating the tag. Let's wait for few more days if anyone disagrees (please comment and/or down-vote this answer if you do). If there would be no disagreement about it I'll create the tag and add it to the already existing questions.

**EDIT**
I started re-tagging from the highest up-votes questions. Check [birthday-paradox](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birthday-paradox) tag.

Comment: +1. See here: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/3101/28666 for some useful advice about creating new tags.

Comment: Cool. Now you can accept your own answer :)

Comment: (+1) The birthday "paradox" is not of major importance in probability as well as in statistics, so I do not see much incentive in creating this tag. It is called a paradox because of the counter-intuitive exponential decrease of the probability of no coincidence of rare events.